# How to customize URL pattern in WSO2AM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I am designing an API using WSO2AM 2.0 
My service is like : `http://190.100.10.10:9000/abc/xyz/doPost<br>`

I want to replace `/abc/xyz/doPost` by `/<MY_CUSTOM_PATH>/doPost`

How can I make a custom URL pattern to hide my original URL path from the service?
Like: `http://<WSO2AM_GENERATED_HOST>/WSO2AM_CONTEXT/WSO2AM_VERSION/<MY_CUSTOM_PATH>/doPost`

I have searched the docs, but I am not able to find any related tutorial.
If I put `/abc/xyz/doPost` it will get appended to the WSO2AM generated hostname.

What is "EDIT SOURCE" in the image below? 
Can it be used to do what I want? If YES, How??
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There aren't anything like WSO2AM_CONTEXT or WSO2AM_VERSION. You can provide any value for the context and version. Version can be String, numbers, etc.

In your case, you can use `abc` as context and `xyz` as the version.

Comment: WSO2AM_CONTEXT or WSO2AM_VERSION is referring to the context and version we put.... and I don't want to use "abc" as context and "xyz" as version.
Can I somehow modify my URL Path?

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi, You can't modify the context once you have created the API. In the API Manager next release, you can customize the URL. I guess, you can use Load Balancer to route the request to your API with custom URL

Comment: Can I modify it while I am designing the API on WSO?

Comment: You can provide any value for the context.

Comment: When is the new version coming? I am using latest 2.0

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly the kind of URL you would get in [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud): `http://your.custom.url/api-name/version/context`. See this tutorial for details: https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Customize+the+API+Store+and+Gateway+URLs

Comment: I am not using WSO cloud. I have the zip version installed on my local Machine.

Comment: Sure. My point is that if it works that way in the cloud, that means that the product is capable of it already (cloud is the same product - just set up and maintained by WSO2).

Answer (score 0):

It might not be complicated...

In publisher interface, when you add/edit an API, in "Implementation" screen, just configure WSO2 APIM to point to "http://190.100.10.10:9000/abc/xyz" - this way, "/abc/xyz" will not be visible to your clients.

So in this case,

```
http://<WSO2AM_GENERATED_HOST>/WSO2AM_CONTEXT/WSO2AM_VERSION/doPost
```

will point to:

```
http://190.100.10.10:9000/abc/xyz/doPost
```

If you wanted to add additional custi=om paths, in the "Design" screen you attached, you can also add your "(MY_CUSTOM_PATH)/doPost" path there.

This way

```
http://<WSO2AM_GENERATED_HOST>/WSO2AM_CONTEXT/WSO2AM_VERSION/<MY_CUSTOM_PATH>/doPost
```

will point to:

```
http://190.100.10.10:9000/abc/xyz//<MY_CUSTOM_PATH>/doPost
```

(However, your backend services should also have "//doPost" implemented)

Comment: my path sometimes contains different names before doPost. if this works I will then need to create different APIs